# No logro mapear un json con react

Tags: reactjs

estoy intentando pasar estos datos a una tabla en react, puedo acceder hasta el campo anterior del que necesito pero no al que quiero.

```
const database = {
  "Representacion":{
    "IdBaseDatos":"2672",
    "Id":"90851395-db05-4275-a260-37ec646120d2",
    "Clonable":true,
    "ChartType":10,
    "Title":"Estadística de crimen en Cataluña﻿ ",
    "Subtitle":"",
    "Text":"",
    "TitleUrl":"estadistica-crimen-comunidad",
    "TitleUrlForEmbed":"estadistica-crimen-comunidad/90851395-db05-4275-a260-37ec646120d2/cataluna/297",
    "EjeUnidad1Desde":null,
    "EjeUnidad1Hasta":null,
    "EjeUnidad2Desde":null,
    "EjeUnidad2Hasta":null,
    "ComparativaEnFilasEnLugarDeEnColumnas":false,
    "OrdenarPorFechaDescendente":true,
    "Activa":true,
    "ChartData":{
       "Metricas":[
          {
             "FK_Serie":null,
             "FK_Metrica":"3154",
             "Nombre":"Denuncias (Dato acumulados)",
             "NombreCompleto":"Infracciones penales registradas a nivel trimestral - Número de infracciones penales registradas en lo que va de año para homicidios dolosos y asesinatos consumados como tipo de delito registrado y Cataluña como comunidad autónoma",
             "TamagnoMuestraEncuesta":null,
             "SonDatosNumericos":true,
             "Fuente":"Ministerio del Interior",
             "Clasificacion":null,
             "UnidadTipoId":"6",
             "UnidadTipoNombre":"Infracciones penales en lo que va de año",
             "UnidadTipoAbreviatura":"Infracciones penales en lo que va de año",
             "Unidad":"Número de infracciones penales registradas en lo que va de año",
             "EscalaFactor":0.0,
             "EscalaNombre":"Unidades",
             "FK_Escala":null,
             "FK_Fuente":"0",
             "FK_Periodicidad":null,
             "Color":"#f03b20",
             "Orden":0.0,
             "FK_EscalaFormula":null,
             "FK_Formula":0,
             "Datos":[
                {
                   "Guid":"90851395-db05-4275-a260-37ec646120d2",
                   "FK_Metrica":null,
                   "Agno":2021,
                   "Periodo":"Trimestre 1",
                   "ValorTick":"Agresión sexual con penetración",
                   "ValorEjeComun":"0.0000",
                   "Fecha":"2021.2500",
                   "ValorEjeUnidad":119.000000000000000000,
                   "Estado":"Definitivo",
                   "Notas":"",
                   "Color":"#f03b20",
                   "FK_Serie":null,
                   "DatoValor":0.0,
                   "FK_DatoValor":null,
                   "PeriodoNombre":"Trimestre 1",
                   "PeriodoValor":0,
                   "DatoValorEstadoNombre":null,
                   "DatoValorNotas":null,
                   "DatoValorFuenteNombre":null,
                   "DatoValorFuente":null,
                   "PeriodicidadFactorAnual":0.0,
                   "PeriodicidadNombre":null,
                   "PeriodicidadId":0,
                   "PeriodoPadre":null
                },
                {
                   "Guid":"90851395-db05-4275-a260-37ec646120d2",
                   "FK_Metrica":null,
                   "Agno":2021,
                   "Periodo":"Trimestre 1",
                   "ValorTick":"Homicidios dolosos y asesinatos consumados",
                   "ValorEjeComun":"1.0000",
                   "Fecha":"2021.2500",
                   "ValorEjeUnidad":14.000000000000000000,
                   "Estado":"Definitivo",
                   "Notas":"",
                   "Color":"#f03b20",
                   "FK_Serie":null,
                   "DatoValor":0.0,
                   "FK_DatoValor":null,
                   "PeriodoNombre":"Trimestre 1",
                   "PeriodoValor":0,
                   "DatoValorEstadoNombre":null,
                   "DatoValorNotas":null,
                   "DatoValorFuenteNombre":null,
                   "DatoValorFuente":null,
                   "PeriodicidadFactorAnual":0.0,
                   "PeriodicidadNombre":null,
                   "PeriodicidadId":0,
                   "PeriodoPadre":null
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "EscalaEje":{
          "3154":{
             "EscalaNombre":"Unidades",
             "EscalaFactor":0,
             "EscalaFactorAjusteDatos":0
          }
       }
    },
    "FK_RegionValor":297,
    "EsEjeEnFuncionDelTiempo":false
 },
};
```

lo envio con

Ahora, el componente PackageDataTable:

```
    import React from "react";

const PackageDataTable = ({ database }) => {
  const datos = database?.Representacion?.ChartData?.Metricas?.Datos || [];

  return (
    <table className="default-table manage-job-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Valor Tick</th>
          <th>Valor Eje Unidad</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {datos.map((dato, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{index + 1}</td>
            <td className="trans-id">{dato.ValorTick}</td>
            <td className="expiry">{dato.ValorEjeUnidad}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default PackageDataTable;
```

ahora bien... si entro con:
const datos = database?.Representacion?.ChartData?.Metricas || [];

{datos.map((dato, index) => (

{index + 1}
{dato.NombreCompleto}

))}

el valor se muestra correctamente...

pero yo necesito ingresar dentro de Datos porque el array que quiero mostrar es el de Datos

osea asi:
const datos = database?.Representacion?.ChartData?.Metricas?.Datos || [];

{datos.map((dato, index) => (

{index + 1}
{dato.ValorTick}
{dato.ValorEjeUnidad}

))}

ya que el resto del codigo del JSON no me es de utilidad en esta tabla.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, no me habia dado cuenta que habia un mapeo dentro de un objeto dentro de otro mapeo.

```
import React from "react";

const PackageDataTable = ({ database }) => {
  const metricas = database?.Representacion?.ChartData?.Metricas || [];

  return (
    <table className="default-table manage-job-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Valor Tick</th>
          <th>Valor Eje Unidad</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {metricas.map((metrica, index) => (
          metrica.Datos.map((dato, datoIndex) => (
            <tr key={datoIndex}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
              <td className="trans-id">{dato.ValorTick}</td>
              <td className="expiry">{dato.ValorEjeUnidad}</td>
            </tr>
          ))
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default PackageDataTable;
```